# Calculate possible sums of int list list recursively

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

I'm struggling to write the code, that will calculate sum of int list list. For example, if we consider following list

```
[[1],[1,5],[7],[2,3,4]]
```

we can get different possible sums, depending on which integer we choose every time:

```
[11,12,13,15,16,17]
```

Can someone give possible ways (not necessary the code) I could solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my attempt to make tail-recursive (kinda) version of algorithm with using lists and pattern matching only. It is written in OCaml, not SML and requires ascending order of inner lists

```
let reverse list = 
    let rec iter list acc :int list = match list with
    [] -> acc
    | x::xs -> iter xs (x::acc)
 in iter list [];;

let listAdd num list = 
  let rec iter num list acc :int list = match list with
     [] -> acc
    | x::xs -> iter num xs ((x + num)::acc)
  in reverse( iter num list []);;   

let listMerge listX listY = 
  let rec iter listX listY acc : int list = match listX with 
     [] -> (reverse acc) @ listY
     | x :: xs -> match listY with 
        [] -> (reverse acc ) @ listX
        | y :: ys -> match ( compare x y ) with
           0  ->  iter xs ys ( x::acc )
          |(-1) ->  iter xs listY ( x::acc )    
          | 1 ->  iter listX ys ( y::acc )
  in iter listX listY [];;  

let listSums listX listY =
 let rec iter listX listY acc = match listX with 
   [] -> acc
   | x :: xs -> iter xs listY ( listMerge acc (listAdd x listY ) )
 in iter listX listY [];;  

let possibleSums shallowList = match shallowList with 
   [] -> []
   | headList :: lists -> 
      let rec iter acc lists  = match lists with 
          [] -> acc
          | headList :: other -> iter ( listSums acc headList ) other  
      in iter headList lists;;
```

here  `possibleSums [[1];[1;5];[7];[2;3;4]];;` evaluates to `int list = [11; 12; 13; 15; 16; 17]`

So basically logical steps are:

- the `reverse` function is just an utility to restore order after resulting accumulator is built - usual concept for tail recursive optimisation
- the `listAdd` function to avoid using map utility in constructing summaries
- the `listMerge` function equal to set union to use sorted lists as integer sets
- the `listSums` function for mapping summation to cartesian product of two sets
- the `posibleSums` function for final level of mapping summation to full cartesian product of all sets.

This algorithm is not just avoiding stack overflow in recursion through TCO, but also providing near optimal solution for this calculation problem.

Also this solution can be further improved with adding premature [merge sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) and removing repeating elements from sets, so inner set order is now insignificant:

```
let split lst = 
    let rec iter lst partX partY = match lst with
        [] -> partX,partY
        | x::xs -> iter xs partY (x::partX)
    in iter lst [] [];;

let rec mergeSort lst = match lst with 
    [] -> []
    |[x] -> [x]
    | _ -> let partX,partY = split lst in
           listMerge (mergeSort partX) (mergeSort partY);;

let possibleSums shallowList = match shallowList with 
   [] -> []
   | headList :: lists -> 
      let rec iter acc lists  = match lists with 
          [] -> acc
          | headList :: other -> iter ( listSums acc (mergeSort headList) ) other  
      in iter (mergeSort headList) lists;;
```

You can test its efficiency on simple example. Let's define repeat function for making repetitive lists:

```
 let rec repeat elem n = match n with
     0 -> []
    | _ -> elem :: (repeat elem (n - 1));;
```

In that case `possibleSums( repeat( repeat 1 30) 30 )` will calculate correct singleton answer  `int list = [30]` in no time. While more straightforward solutions (like Jesper's one) will do it forever.

Comment: Without saying to much, my simple solution could be optimised with a "running" sum instead of generating the list of lists and then summing them. However it would probably not be a match anyways :)

Comment: @Jesper.Reenberg The problem not in the method of generation. Just for case of integer numbers the set of all possible number combinations is far too large. This solution is fast because of dropping repetitions in intermediate results, so it keeps polynomial complexity based on initial number count and estimate result length.

Answer (score 1):

The following is an attempt at breaking the steps up in readable and hopefully understandable parts

```
fun sums xss =
    let
      fun extend xss y = map (fn xs => y :: xs) xss
      fun extend' xss ys = foldl (fn (y, b) => extend xss y @ b) [] ys
      fun extend'' xss = foldl (fn (xs,b) => extend' b xs) [[]] xss
      fun sum xs = foldl op+ 0 xs
    in
      map sum (extend'' xss)
    end


- sums [[1],[1,5],[7],[2,3,4]];
val it = [17,13,16,12,15,11] : int list
```

Obviously most of the functions could have been made to take the arguments as pairs in the correct order and thus have been given directly to the map and fold functions instead of wrapping them in anonymous functions.

Comment: thanks! do you think it's possible to implement this function without using map and foldl? I'm doing a programming course and these functions are not yet allowed :) I tried to implement it using pattern-matching and recursion, but stuck completely...

Comment: Anything is possible. You can implement your own map and fold functions, or even specialised versions of them, however in the later case you could probably inline it all into one function.

Answer (score -2):

i would try to solve it with a recursive loop - in pseudocode:

```
sum = 0;

while (i < arrayOfArrays.length ) {
     sumUp(arrayOfArrayElements);
     i ++
 }

 function sumUp() {
     while( j < arrayOfArrayElement.length){
     sum = sum + arrayOfArrayElement[j].val
     j ++

  }


}
```

so you call a function which sums up every array element of an array and sums the values up together inside a function which calls that function for every element inside that array of arrays. lolz

> 1. create a function which takes an array of ints and adds the containing ints with a for or while loop .
> 2. loop over the main array and call for every containing array element the function for suming up until there are no more elements left, you can achieve this by working with the .length of the array which should be accessible in every script/programming language

Comment: your pseudo code solves different problem bud, isn't is clear enough?

Comment: hey buddy, then maybe your question isnt clear enough? i think you want to get the sum of ints in lists in a list.

Comment: 1) look at the example, I guess you even didn't look 2) your solution is not even recursive

Comment: well i dont get the issue, thanks for the hint and good luck.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23585/discussion-between-thegrunt-and-damluar)

Comment: Your solution uses a very imperative mindset, which is kinda useless for coding in SML, which is a functional language.